# Video controls are not visible while playing the video in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i am developing application using ionic in that app i need to display videos by getting the URL's from the server i done with that part.while playing the video in the app it will not showing controllers link pause and volume and other options. Controls  are showing before video start and after video completed.I used the below code to display video in the ionic app.

```
<video controls>
<source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
    type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<video style="width: 100%;height: 200px;align-items: center;" src="{{video.src}}#t=0.1" controls >

      </video>
```